# Function eregi_replace() is deprecated

Tags: php, gateway, eregi

I am getting this error message appear when trying to support to a payment gateway:

```
Message: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated
Message: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated
```

This is the code its relating to in the payment gateway

```
        $response = eregi_replace ( "[[:space:]]+", " ", $response );
        $response = eregi_replace ( "[\n\r]", "", $response );
```

Any help in solving this error would be great!

Comment: quadrizillion duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eregi+is+deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a function is deprecated, it means it's not supported anymore and the use of it is discouraged. In fact, all `eregi` functions are deprecated.

You should try another function, such as `preg_replace()`. This could mean you have to edit your regular expression.

This should work

```
$response = preg_replace ("/\s+/", " ", $response);
$response = preg_replace ("/[\r\n]/", "", $response);
```

Comment: All the preg_replace are causing Message: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser warning : xmlParsePITarget: invalid name prefix 'xml' error

Comment: in your first replace you should leave one space as the replacement..

Comment: Oh my apologies for my typo! I edited my answer. Thanks @SeRPRo

Comment: @TimS. we all have typos sometimes.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines to

```
 $response = preg_replace ( "~[ ]+~", " ", $response );
 $response = str_replace ( array("\n", "\r"), "", $response );
```

which uses `str_replace` & `preg_replace`, non-deprecated functions.

Comment: What if there are 3 spaces in a row?

Comment: Well for the first one I think he does because you only remove double space.. but what if there are three?

Comment: @Marcus: if there are 3 space in a row, there will be 2 of them replaced to one, it will result in 2 spaces which will result in one space

Comment: @Martin that's not true since the replace doesn't start over from the beginning: http://codepad.org/4jD3ONN8

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines to

```
$response = preg_replace ( "/[[:space:]]+/", " ", $response );
$response = preg_replace ( "/[\n\r]/", "", $response );
```

which uses PCRE, the preferred engine and the reason EREG is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for that:

```
$response = preg_replace("#[\r\n]#", "", $response);
$response = preg_replace("#\s+#m", "$1", $response);
```